# Broadcast motion sensor data attached to Adafruit feather M0

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone, adafruit

I have a motion sensor attached to pin 12 on the feather M0 BLE device. I got the beacon to broadcast its manufacturing minor and major...etc
but what I am looking for is to also broadcast the sensor value which is 0 or 1.

I am NOT looking to use GATT because I do not want to connect to the device.

I would like to either use beacon or eddystone.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?  Can't you just alter the minor between 1 and 0 based on the sensor?

Comment: I never thought about doing this, I was concentrating on adding another field.  I am not an expert at BLE but I thought these values are important for the packet?

Comment: The major and minor identifiers can be used however you like.  I would recommend putting the sensor value in the minor

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine.  but I believe I have another issue now, is when I have the feather connected to USB I can see the data via Bluetooth (Android, UWP apps) but when I have it only connected to battery the data does not change and even the program on the feather does not seem to work.  the way I know that is I blink the red light on sensor data change.  when connecting to usb I can see the data dn the red light action

Comment: I'd suggest posting this second issue as new question to attract attention of someone with experience getting the Adafruit Feather working under battery power